# How can this attempt to implement a Milstein numerical approximation for an Ito process of multiple components be fixed?

Tags: matlab, numerical-modelling, stochastic-ode

I have been reading Kloeden and Platen's Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations, and have more or less been trying to systematically complete the various exercises therein as I go along. I have been effectively stuck on a single problem for a long while, and despite returning to attack it periodically, I have not been successful. At this point, naturally, I am pretty desperate for any insight that might lead me to finally moving past it. To that end, I shall try my best to explain my problem succinctly.

I am given the following Ito process:
$(1)$ $dX_t = -\frac{1}{2}X_tdt + X_tdW_t^1 + X_tdW_t^2$,

which I have determined has the exact solution given by $(2)$  $X_t = X_0e^{((-\frac{1}{2} - 1^2)t + 1\cdot(W_t^1 + W_t^2))}$,

where here I write the drift coefficient $ a = -\frac{1}{2}$ distinct from the diffusion coefficient $b = 1.0$ for clarity later. Also, $X_0 = 1$. I will add that this text makes the (I think) somewhat regrettable convention choice of writing $a(x,t)$ shorthand as simply $a$. So a regular sight is to see something like "$a(x,t) = ax$" where the latter $a$ is of course just the constant $-\frac{1}{2}$ I mentioned. Similarly, "$b(x,t) = bx$" in this problem. (Also, this all corresponds to the SDE introduced in question 10.2.1 of Kloeden.)

Now, my problem is a later one, 10.3.3, in which I am to implement the following generalized Milstein numerical scheme for a $k$-dimensional Ito process with $m$ components. In the case here, k = 1 and m = 2:

$(3)$ $Y_{n+1}^k = Y_n^k + \underline{a}^k\Delta + \sum_{j=1}^m b^{k,j}\Delta W^j + \sum_{{j_1,j_2}=1}^m\underline{L}^{j_1}b^{k,j_2}J_{(j_1,j_2)}$,

with $\Delta$ = the step size = $h$ in my code, $\Delta W^j$ = the $n$-th Gaussian increment of the Wiener process $W^j$, and so in the implementation, $\Delta W^j$ = $\sqrt{h}\cdot W_n$, with $W_n$ the $n$-th standard normal random number, which in my case is generated using Matlab's $randn$ function. $\underline{a} = a - \frac{1}{2}bb'$, $\underline{L}^{j_1} = \sum_{{i}=1}^kb^{i,j_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}$, the usual Stratonovich operator for obtaining the coefficient functions.

Finally, the Stratonovich integrals themselves, $J_{(j_1,j_2)}$, are approximated in the following way:

$J^p_{(j_1,j_2)} = \Delta\Big(\frac{1}{2}\xi_{j_1}\xi_{j_2} + \sqrt{\rho_p}(\mu_{j_1,p}\xi_{j_2} - \mu_{j_2,p}\xi_{j_1})\Big) + \frac{\Delta}{2\pi}\sum_{{r}=1}^p\Big[\frac{1}{r}\big(\zeta_{j_1,r}\big(\sqrt{2}\xi_{j_2} + \eta_{j_2,r}\big) - \zeta_{j_2,r}\big(\sqrt{2}\xi_{j_1} + \eta_{j_1,r}\big)\big)\Big]$,

where $\rho_p = \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sum_{{r}=1}^p\frac{1}{r^2}$.

$p \in \mathbb{N} $, with larger $p$ producing a better approximation, $\xi_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta}}\Delta W^j = W_n^j$. Again, I think the notation here is somewhat ambiguous, but basically it seems to me it would be clearer to write  $\xi_n^j = W_n^j$ to make it absolutely clear that it is the $n$-th value of $\xi_j$. In any case, $\xi_j,\mu_{j,p},\zeta_{j,r},$ and $\eta_{j,r}$ are independent $N(0;1)$ Gaussian random variables.

Now, I honestly don't know at this point if I have been too explicit to the point of pedantic in defining things, or not enough-- I really don't think I am personally at the level of competence in this subject yet that I have any sense at all of what "should be taken for granted". But if I've left anything out or haven't been clear enough, I am quite happy to come back and remedy that as needed.

So after all that, my problem is that my implementation doesn't seem to work and after weeks of writing and re-writing it, I can't seem to make it work. And sadly, I have literally no other colleagues available I can talk to about this. So I am desperately hoping someone here has the knowledge and willingness to look over what I have done, and hopefully spot and point out whatever mistake I have made. As it stands, this ought to be a strong order 1.0 method, but my implementation isn't displaying any error convergence behavior with decreasing step size at all. And honestly, it's driving me mad. I do not know what I am missing. Anyway, without further ado, here is what I have (for use in Matlab):

```
clear;

t0 = 0;
T = 1;
X0 = 1.0; 
a = -0.5;
b = 1.0;

p = 2;

trajectories = 1000;
error = [];

for N = [16,32,64,128];
trajsum = 0;
for i1 = 1:trajectories;
    
    h = (T-t0)/N;
    
    W1 = randn(1,N+1);
    W1(1) = 0;
    W2 = randn(1,N+1);
    W2(1) = 0;
    
    delW1 = zeros(1,N);
    delW1(1,1:N) = W1(1,2:N+1)*sqrt(h);
    delW2 = zeros(1,N);
    delW2(1,1:N) = W2(1,2:N+1)*sqrt(h);
    
    sumdelW1 = zeros(1,N);
    sumdelW2 = zeros(1,N);
    
    for i = 1:N;
        tempsum1 = 0;
        tempsum2 = 0;
        for j = 1:i;
            tempsum1 = tempsum1 + delW1(1,j);
            tempsum2 = tempsum2 + delW2(1,j);
        end
        sumdelW1(1,i) = tempsum1;
        sumdelW2(1,i) = tempsum2;
    end
    
    milE1 = delW1/sqrt(h);
    milE2 = delW2/sqrt(h);
    
    milstein = zeros(1,N+1);
    milstein(1,1) = X0;
    
    exact2 = zeros(1,N+1);
    exact2(1,1) = X0;
    
    for i = 1:N;
        milstein(1,i+1) = milstein(1,i) + (a - b^2/2)*milstein(1,i)*h + b*milstein(1,i)*(delW1(1,i) + delW2(1,i)) + (1/2)*b^2*milstein(1,i)*((delW1(1,i))^2 + (delW2(1,i))^2) + b^2*milstein(1,i)*(J12(h,p,milE1(1,i),milE2(1,i)) + J21(h,p,milE1(1,i),milE2(1,i)));
        exact2(1,i+1) = X0*exp((a - (b^2))*h*i + b*(sumdelW1(1,i) + sumdelW2(1,i)));
    end
    trajsum = trajsum + abs(milstein(1,N+1) - exact2(1,N+1));
end
trajsum = (1/trajectories)*trajsum;
error = [error trajsum];
end

error

figure(1);
subplot(1,1,1);
plot([0:h:1],exact2(1,1:N+1),'k-');
hold on;
plot([0:h:1],milstein(1,1:N+1),'r--');
```

Moreover, I use the following two functions to simulate the stochastic integrals.

J12 given by:

```
function a = J12(h,p,E1,E2);
N1 = randn(1,p);
N2 = randn(1,p);
C1 = randn(1,p);
C2 = randn(1,p);
U1 = randn;
U2 = randn;

pp = 0;

for i = 1:p;
    pp = pp + 1/i^2;
end

pp = (1/12) - (1/(2*(pi^2)))*pp; % This completes getting rho-P.

a = h*((0.5)*E1*E2 + sqrt(pp)*(U1*E2 - U2*E1));

y = 0;
for k = 1:p;
    y = y + (1/k)*(C1(1,k)*(sqrt(2)*E2 + N2(1,k)) - C2(1,k)*(sqrt(2)*E1 + N1(1,k)));
end

a = a + (h/(2*pi))*y;

end
```

And J21 given by:

```
function a = J21(h,p,E1,E2);
N1 = randn(1,p);
N2 = randn(1,p);
C1 = randn(1,p);
C2 = randn(1,p);
U1 = randn;
U2 = randn;

pp = 0;

for i = 1:p;
    pp = pp + 1/i^2;
end

pp = (1/12) - (1/(2*(pi^2)))*pp; % This completes getting rho-P.

a = h*((0.5)*E2*E1 + sqrt(pp)*(U2*E1 - U1*E2));

y = 0;
for k = 1:p;
    y = y + (1/k)*(C2(1,k)*(sqrt(2)*E1 + N1(1,k)) - C1(1,k)*(sqrt(2)*E2 + N2(1,k)));
end

a = a + (h/(2*pi))*y;

end
```

Anyway my apologies for the essay. Of course I am happy to clean it up if it doesn't conform to standards. As to the problems, regardless of the choice of p, or N (the number of steps) that I divide the interval into, checking the "error" variable makes it clear that the error is not showing the order of convergence this method is supposed to have, nor indeed any convergence at all. I am sincerely grateful to anyone willing to give this a look. Thank you.